# Reading cookie from the request through Lua + nginx script

Tags: nginx, cookies, lua

I was trying to read the cookie from the HTTP request in Nginx layer through lua script. But it always returns a null value. I'm not sure what am I missing here. Below is my code snippet

```
local ck = require "resty.cookie"

local field, err = ck:get("jwt-token")
```

The "jwt-token" is the cookie name and is present in the "/" path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method worked for me 
`lua
local token = ngx.var.cookie_MYTOKEN
ngx.say(token)`

Here is the reference

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/issues/19